# How do I prevent GridBagLayout from doing micro changes?

Tags: java, swing, kotlin, gridbaglayout

I'm using `GridBagLayout` to create a GUI in Java.
I have three fields, one on the left and two on top of each other on the right.
I have set the weight variables accordingly and if I don't add anything, the ratios seem right.
The problem is that when I add an element to the field on the upper right, the ratio between it and the one below changes. This happens until the content is too large for the panel and the `JScrollPane` kicks in.

[image]

My code:

```kotlin
val frame = JFrame("test")
frame.layout = BorderLayout()
val panel1 = JPanel(GridBagLayout())
val panel2 = JPanel().apply {
    layout = BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)
}
val panel3 = JPanel(BorderLayout())
val scrollPane = JScrollPane(panel2)
panel1.add(scrollPane, GridBagConstraints().apply {
    gridx = 0
    gridy = 0
    weighty = 0.75
    weightx = 1.0
    fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH
})
panel1.add(panel3, GridBagConstraints().apply {
    gridx = 0
    gridy = 1
    weighty = 0.25
    weightx = 1.0
    fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH
})
val button = JButton("text")
var counter = 0
button.addActionListener({
    panel2.removeAll()
    for (i in 0 until ++counter) {
        panel2.add(JLabel("some text"))
    }
    frame.revalidate()
    frame.repaint()
})
panel3.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER)
frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER)
frame.setSize(480, 234)
frame.revalidate()
frame.repaint()
frame.isVisible = true
```

Comment: Post [mre] please

Comment: @c0der updated...

Comment: I still can not copy-paste run. The code as posted does not compile.

Comment: @c0der i copied what was in my main method... It's kotlin, not Java, just in case.